# Extracting a date from a filename and converting it in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract the date from a filename and assign the converted date to a variable.

E.g.

```
Filename="SomeFilename 05 May 2022.zip"
```

And I want to extract *05052022* and assign that to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The following method is a little lengthy but you can use a bash regex for extracting the date parts and a `case` switch for converting the month:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

filename='SomeFilename 05 May 2022.zip'

if [[ $filename =~ ([0-9]{2})\ ([A-Z][a-z]{2})\ ([0-9]{4})\.[^.]+$ ]]
then
    d=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

    case ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} in
    Jan) m=01;; Feb) m=02;; Mar) m=03;;
    Apr) m=04;; May) m=05;; Jun) m=06;;
    Jul) m=07;; Aug) m=08;; Sep) m=09;;
    Oct) m=10;; Nov) m=11;; Dec) m=12;;
    esac

    y=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

    date=$d$m$y
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) (PCRE mode) + the `date` command:

```
Filename="SomeFilename 05 May 2022.zip"
date=$(grep -oP '\d{2}\s+\w+\s+\d{4}(?=\.zip)' <<< "$Filename")
res=$(date -d "$date" '+%d%m%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Filename="Some File name 03 May 2022.txt"
$ awk -F[' .'] '{mydate=$(NF-3)$(NF-2)$(NF-1)" +%d%m%Y"; print|"date -d " mydate}' <<<"$Filename"
03052022
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the month names aren't fixed 3-letters wide, just a lookup string suffices

**CODE**

```
# gawk profile, created Wed May 25 03:54:41 2022
# BEGIN rule(s)

BEGIN {  _ = "[0-9 ]"
             gsub(".",(_),_)
             gsub(OFS, "",_)
        __ = _
         _ = "JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC"

    sub("[^\\]]+[]][^\\]]+[]]","& ("(_)") ",__)
               sub("9",     "3",__)
    sub(" [[][0][-][9]"," [0-2",__)
     ___="|"_
      _+=_^=_<_
} { 
     $-__=toupper($-__) 

}    gsub(__,    "\4""&\3")+\
     gsub("^[^\4]*[\4]|[\3][^\3]*$","") + \
      sub("[^0-9]+",                       \
  sprintf("%0*.f",_,(_+index(___,substr($-__,_+_++,_)))/(--_+_)))'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
05052022
```